# python maskpass.askpass() doesn't allow input

Tags: python

When I wrote this code it didn't let me input a password. I am very new to programming so I would appreciate any help.

import maskpass
pwd = maskpass.askpass()
print(pwd)

Expected:
Enter password: (and then a box to input my password)

Actually got:
Enter password:

Comment: What do you mean “and then a box to input my password”.  The password is entered into the terminal, as shown in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The python `maskpass.askpass()` function mask user inputs so, you can't see your actions on the screen, but if you can't even type anything on your screen it may occur because may your `terminal/console` you're using doesn't support the necessary functionalities.